# Cannot send sms using AWS sns outside Sandbox

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am unable to send messages after movin gout of sandbox environment, the logs shows following message for failure:
**"No origination identity available to send to destination number"**
I want to use this service in Us-East 1 Region (N-Virginia).
smsType is Transactional
How can I set orignation number or  can I send using custom/random sender id instead?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending SMS to the US? In that case, you'll need to purchase an origination identity to deliver your SMS with. The easiest way would be to get a toll-free number: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-origination-numbers.html.

To then use this, you can supply this as a message attribute to  your `Publish` request. There's an example for that here: [Can you specify origination number on SMS send? (aws-sdk-js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573881/can-you-specify-origination-number-on-sms-send-aws-sdk-js).